.NET8 Open ID connect required restarting when editing app details
Below is my program.cs class. I placed my Azure app details like clientid, secret and tenant id in appsettings.json file. It is working fine when we initially run the application but I want when we edit the app details in appsettings.json file, it start accepting new app without restart. As of now it only take app change effect after restart.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using OpenIDConnect.Models;
using OpenIDConnect.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add configuration
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    //.AddJsonFile("azureAdConfig.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var configurationRoot = configurationBuilder.Build();
builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(configurationRoot);

// Register services
builder.Services.Configure<AzureAdOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<AzureAdOptions>, ConfigureAzureAdOptions>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<JsonConfigService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomOpenIdConnectService>();

// Configure authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) // Cookie-based authentication
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var azureAdOptionsMonitor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<AzureAdOptions>>();
    var azureAdOptions = azureAdOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue;

    // Set initial values
    options.ClientId = azureAdOptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureAdOptions.TenantId}/v2.0";
    options.ClientSecret = azureAdOptions.ClientSecret;

    // Additional configuration
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var azureAdOptionsMonitor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<AzureAdOptions>>();
        var azureAdOptions = azureAdOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue;
        var openIdConnectService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<CustomOpenIdConnectService>();

        // Invalidate the cache to force a refresh
        openIdConnectService.InvalidateMetadata(azureAdOptions.TenantId, azureAdOptions.ClientId, azureAdOptions.ClientSecret, azureAdOptions.Domain);

        context.Options.ClientId = azureAdOptions.ClientId;
        context.Options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureAdOptions.TenantId}/v2.0";
        context.Options.ClientSecret = azureAdOptions.ClientSecret;
        
        context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = azureAdOptions.Domain;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});


builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build


There is .net configuration to implement this. You could try IOptionsMonitor to react to configuration changes in real-time without needing to restart your application.
appsettings
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx",
    "TenantId": "xxx"
  }
}

You need a class for options
public class AzureAdOptions
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}

Register the services for further use
builder.Services.Configure<AzureAdOptions>
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAzureAdService, AzureAdService>();

Then you could access configuration through service
public class SomeService{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<AzureAdOptions> _azureAdOptions;
    public SomeService(IOptionsMonitor<AzureAdOptions> azureAdOptions)
    {
        _azureAdOptions = azureAdOptions;
    }
    ...
}

For more details: https://medium.com/@ludmal/net-configuration-with-ioptions-ioptionsmonitor-and-ioptionssnapshot-76e0efb0ad87

Hi @Fengzhi Zhou,
Thank you for your response.
IOptionsMonitor only detects changes in the config file, which my existing code already handles. To verify this, I updated my program file, but the output remained the same.
When editing the config file and authenticating in a different browser or incognito mode, the code reaches "OnRedirectToIdentityProvider" and all properties are set correctly. However, I receive the following error. (See next Comment because of character limit)

AADSTS90072: User account 'amit@xyz.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/tenantid/' does not exist in tenant 'abc def' and cannot access the application 'appid'(AppName) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in ...
The issue is that while the tenant ID and app ID are correct, the tenant name is outdated. Have you used "OnRedirectToIdentityProvider" to modify app details without restarting the application? The changes take effect only after a restart.

The issue might be the caching before OnRedirectToIdentityProvider , have you verified no extra caching?

Yes, you can see it in my Program.cs file.
Additionally, I tried manually deleting cookies from the browser, running the application in a new browser, and even in incognito mode.
I checked with many of my friends, but it is not working for anyone. Could you please confirm if it is working for you? That would give me some confidence.
